# Describe typescript object where some keys are known

Tags: typescript, types

How can I define a type for my typescript object where some of the keys are known, others are either unknown or defined as a separate type.

Take the following object:

```
{
  foo: 1,
  bar: "abc",
  baz: {
    foobar: 2
  },
  foobaz: {
    foobar: 1
  }
}
```

I know the object will always have the properties `foo` and `bar` as defined in this type:

```
type MyObject = {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
}
```

But I know that the object *may* have other properties and if they do, they will always have the same structure of an object with a property foobar and a value of the type number.

How do I defined this type?

I tried:

```
type MyObject = {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
  [key: string]?: {
    foobar: number;
  }
}
```

But it appears you can't declare a generic key like that when you have explicit keys in the same type.

I actually know the possible values of the "unknown" properties. So I tried this:

```
type MyList = 'baz'|'foobaz';

type MyObject = {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
  [key in MyList]?: {
    foobar: number;
  }
}
```

The `[key in MyList]` part works alone, but as soon as I combine it with the explicit properties I get an error: "'MyList' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here". I tried the same with an Enum and got the same result.

Comment: So, do you know the keys or not?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no specific type in TypeScript that works this way.  You'd want an index signature instead of a mapped type, but you can't declare a "rest index signature".  See the linked question and its answer for the situation and various workarounds and approaches.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, since you know the value of the properties, they should just be optional and hardcoded to the same type.

> A mapped type may not declare properties or methods.

```
type Inner = {
    foobar: number;
};

type MyObject = {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
  baz?: Inner;
  foobaz?: Inner;
}
```

[See an example of an alternative](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=39&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAyBLAzsKBeKByARgQwC8sAfLAMwHsL8iBuAKHtElhAHkcArCAYzUwDe9KFADaAawggoiAHaskqALoB%20AFxQhIkZWp4AThtkBXALY4I%20hiIC%209O03DQ4HbnwBMGTcKi6jZiysffEMoVH05AHMGB2Zndi5eYABmLxdEjygAMlZXJIYAE14AGwNoADcDKDwNdLcUhno8ADpGIA) that still uses mapped types is to AND (`&`)two types:

```
type MyList = 'baz'|'foobaz';

type MyObject = {
  [key in MyList]?: {
    foobar: number;
  }
}

type MyObject2 = {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
}

type MyObject3 = MyObject2 & MyObject;

// Alternatively

type MyObject =  {
  [key in MyList]?: {
    foobar: number;
  }
} & {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
};
```

[image: Screenshot of Typescript]